# What is the reasoning behind javascript null zero comparison differences?

Tags: javascript

I'm asking  this off the back of a Jeff Atwood [tweet](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/476826733576847360) which shows the following outcomes of null / zero comparison in javascript:

[image: null zero comparison in javascript]

I've seen this before and as amusing as it is, I'm wondering if there is actually logic or reasoning behind the behaviour?

Comment: I mean, the spec explains the operator behaviors: http://es5.github.io/#x11.8 (I don't feel like following the paths for every scenario)

Comment: Your example and a quick glance at http://zero.milosz.ca/ provide good reasons for the importance of using '===' unless you know **exactly** why you might want to use loose comparisons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0 == null` is never `true`. With "loose comparison" `null` is only equal to itself or to `undefined`.

However, the relational operator(s) converts its operands to numbers first, if any of those is a number. So, since `0` is a number, `null` is converted to a number. And the mathematical value to `null` is `0`. So you end up comparing

```
0 > 0     // nope
0 >= 0    // yes
0 == null // nope, null is only equal to null and undefined
0 <= 0    // yes
0 < 0     // nope
```

These rules are all defined in the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) (whether they make sense or not is a different question).